# why response.redirect cant able to redirect the page once session is expired in global.aspx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, session, web

The strange things happened on The response.redirct cant redirect the necessary page while session is expired in global aspx page.

I tried with below codes but yet no successs!!!!

I tried with **Response.Redirect** As well as **Server.Transfer**

```
        Context.Server.ClearError() 
        Context.Response.AddHeader("Location", "~/frmError.aspx") 
        Context.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = True 
        Context.Response.StatusCode = CInt(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect) 
        Context.Response.Output.Close() 
        Context.Response.End()
```

Comment: write your code in Session_End event in globel.asax

Answer (score 0):

And from where you call Response.Redirect?

Have you tried to call it from `protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)`?

And what exactly happened after session expired? Redirect to login page?

Comment: then how can i redirect to any intermediate page if session expires?

Comment: I found out only that it's not possible. Because how session expires work: This method is called internally without no request. And after session is expired on the server and after request with this old session_id is made, server does't recognize the id and created new one. Only think you can do is handle creating new session. For example check Session.IsNewSession.